# Setting default edges to be square (orthogonal) in a tree drawn with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm searching for a way to have orthogonal edges (only going horizontal and vertical) by default when I draw a tree. I can't seem to find a way to set this as the default style (without having to add edges with path each time).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%%% <
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{10pt}%
%%% >

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{every node}=[draw, rectangle, fill=gray!20]


  \node {root}
  child {node {left}}
  child {node {right}
    child {node {child}}
    child {node {child}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have included an example of the edges I'm searching for. There is not need for labels on the edges.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the key `edge from parent fork down`?

Comment: The provided example is *not* a tree... You can obtain such lines using `(node A) -| (node B)` for drawing from node A to node B first horizontal, then vertical, or `|-` for the opposite?

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust further for your needs

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={draw, rectangle, fill=gray!20},
edge from parent path={
(\tikzparentnode) |-   % Start from parent
($(\tikzparentnode)!0.5!(\tikzchildnode)$) -| % make an ortho line to mid point
(\tikzchildnode)}]                            % make another ortho to the target

  \node {root}
  child {node {left}}
  child {node {right}
    child {node {child}}
    child {node {child}}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get artifacts using this approach (with more "interesting" node labels): the left & right branches to the children have a discontinuity along the horizontal line, I think because `\tikzchildnode` do not align exactly. ----- Workaround: `(\tikzparentnode) -- +(0.0,-0.5\lvl) -| (\tikzchildnode)`, where `\lvl` is the `level distance`.